# Overriding default table schema in spring boot hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

There is a property in spring batch for setting the default schema
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=ABC
Now this is my entity

```
@Table("EMPLOYEE")
class Employee{
}
```

This table is present in schema = DEF and this class is not in my repo and it is coming from another dependency. So I cant add the schema in @Table annotation.

So while inserting the query is

```
em.persist(employee);
insert into ABC.EMPLOYEE VALUES();
```

and the table is present in dEF. How do i pass the schema name while doing em.persist? for em the default schema is ABC

Comment: @DanielJacob :  even if I create EmployeeRepository implements JpaRepository<Employee,String>, same issue would come? how would i override the default schema in jparepository

Comment: Please try this - [multiple schemas usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760964/how-to-use-multiple-schemas-in-one-database-by-using-jpa-hibernate-with-sprin)

Comment: @DineshDontha  i would prefer single PlatformTxnmanager .  But the example there maintains or creates 2 transctionmanagers